# No such method stringIsNullOrEmpty when integrating firebase

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, guava

I'm trying to add Firebase to an old java appengine project built with eclipse.  When I attempt to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options) I end up with this error on the local server running super dev mode (server side error, not client):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Platform.stringIsNullOrEmpty(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
at com.google.common.base.Strings.isNullOrEmpty(Strings.java:67)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(FirebaseApp.java:79)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:168)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:155)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:142)
```

I'm using these on eclipse Neon 4.6.3 with these libraries:

[image]

I've loaded the guava source jar and set a breakpoint on Strings.java:67 and it hits the line and eclipse says it's pulling it from the expected guava jar file.  But darn if it can't seem to find the Platform.string.IsNullOrEmpty method even though I see it in the eclipse jar exploded view.

I've tried guava20.0 with similar issues.

What could cause the jvm to not find the method when it's there in it's own jar file?  Any suggestions for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by removing all my WEB-INF/lib jar, adding back library references, and updating them all to the latest available.  I'm not sure which combination of libraries was causing the problem but for future reference, I ended up with the following configuration:
[image]

And this set of jars:

```html
appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.53.jar        google-api-client-servlet-1.22.0.jar      gwt-servlet.jar
appengine-api-labs.jar                  google-http-client-1.22.0.jar             httpclient-4.0.1.jar
appengine-endpoints-deps.jar            google-http-client-appengine-1.22.0.jar   httpcore-4.0.1.jar
appengine-endpoints.jar                 google-http-client-jackson2-1.22.0.jar    jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
appengine-jsr107cache-1.9.53.jar        google-http-client-jdo-1.22.0.jar         java-json.jar
asm-5.0.4.jar                           google-oauth-client-1.22.0.jar            jdo-api-3.0.1.jar
firebase-admin-4.1.7.jar                google-oauth-client-appengine-1.22.0.jar  jsr107cache-1.1.jar
gin-2.1.2.jar                           google-oauth-client-servlet-1.22.0.jar    jta-1.1.jar
google-api-client-1.22.0.jar            guava-20.0.jar                            log4j.jar
google-api-client-appengine-1.22.0.jar  gwt-gae-channel-2.0.0.jar                 twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar
```